# How to bind a IEnumerable<string> to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, listbox

This may be a very simple question, but at the moment I don't actually know what to google.

If I had an object like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In my VM I have a list of employees (`public List<Employee> Employees`). It's easy to bind this in my Xaml to a ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Employees}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But what if my list of employees would contain strings and not `Employee` objects? How could I bind these string values to the `TextBlock` in the data template?

Comment: You have to set the binding mode, and in that case `mode="two-way"`

Comment: Why do I need to set a two-way binding for text blocks? The one-way binding works the "Property => UI-Element way". A two-way binding is just required for the other way (UI-E => Prop). And you can't change the data in a text block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write `{Binding}` where you specify the binding.

Comment: Thanks! Never used that before.

Comment: You could also use `{Binding Path=.}` which is the same thing, but useful if you wanted a TwoWay binding, because TwoWay bindings require path to be set.